# installed 'go1.13.3.darwin-amd64.pkg' on mac os. Set GOPATH, PATH, GOROOT env variables. But Go doestn't seem to be installed

Tags: macos, go, installation, gopath

I installed `go1.13.3.darwin-amd64.pkg` on Mac. I set env variables in `~/.bash_profile`

`GOPATH = $HOME/gocode`

`GOROOT = /usr/local/go`

`PATH = $PATH:$GOPATH/bin`

saved the edits with `source /.bash_profile`.

Checked `go version` on terminal. But i don't see a go version installed.

Is there anything I've missed.

Comment: Do not set GOROOT. Das /usr/local/go to PATH

Comment: s/Das/Set/ sorry Autokorrekturen in mobile

Answer (score 1):

You can check the env required for go using fallowing command.

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/user/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user/golang"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/golang"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build484316132=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

and if the go command itself is not working then set the PATH correctly which points to go binary, in my case its /usr/bin/go

```
$ which go
/usr/bin/go

$ go version
go version go1.11.5 linux/amd64
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the following configuration in `.bashrc`:

```sh
# Golang
export GOPATH="/opt/DEVOPS/SDK/golang/go_projects"
export GOROOT="/opt/DEVOPS/SDK/golang/go"
export GOBIN="$GOPATH/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOBIN"
```

The first two lines have to reflect your GO path.
The first (`GOPATH`) is where the packages will be stored (`go get`).
The second is related to your go installation.

Than load the new env:

```sh
source /home/$(whoami)/.bashrc
```

Comment: Don't assign variables like this in an rc file. For bash use `.bash_profile`. Do not set GOROOT.

Comment: wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.13.3.src.tar.gz ; tar xf go1.13.3.src.tar.gz and then set the path. Why you haven't to set the GOROOT? I think that is better download and set the GOROOT instead that install with the package manager (yum/apt).

Comment: Where are you reading that you _should_ set GOROOT? Neither installing from the tarball nor from source should have that set, and it can only cause problems.

Comment: Please check "Installing extra Go versions" section on the official installation documentation: https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: Nowhere in that text does it say to set GOROOT, it is determined by the `go` tool itself. In fact this is one of the situations that causes users problems, because sloppy variable handling can lead to the wrong GOROOT being set and breaking the installation.